# How to get the exception type when printing an exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

If I have the code:

```
try:
  1 / 0

except Exception as e:
  my_error = e
  #e is sent to the application user end
```

It returns the text for `e` but not the exception name as well. In the case of the code I need this for, the console isn't open at the time and the exception is sent through to the user end when it is caught. At the moment when an exception occurs I can see the error text, but how do I get the name as well.

In the case of the example I'd like for `my_error` to be

```
ZeroDivisionError: #error text
```

instead of `my_error` only being

```
#error text
```

Comment: `type(e).__name__` for the exception name. `str(e)` for the message. Put 'em together however you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code in exception block.

```
e.__class__.__name__
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @nircraft Thanks for the suggestion. will add details.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking at just the description of the error, you are looking at.

```
 err_str = str(e)
```

But if you are also looking for exception name along with description, you are looking at.

```
 err_str = repr(e)
```

Comment: Just want to add that if you want both the exception name and text, you can instead use `repr(e)`. `str(e) == 'division by zero'`, `repr(e)=="ZeroDivisionError('division by zero',)"`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Updated my answer to reflect your comment